# cannot change number of tokens from 256 to 1

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3 node cassandra cluster and on my seed, the num_tokens is set to 256. I'm trying to set it to 1 or comment it out...but every time when i start cassandra, I get this error:

```
    ERROR 21:28:08 Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot change the number of tokens from 256 to 1
```

I also did a `rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*`

I also tried to go into `system.local` in cql and delete everything in the `tokens` field but I wasn't able to. How do I change this property?

Comment: Because you're blowing away your `/var/lib/cassandra` directory I'm assuming you don't have valuable data in this cluster (or at least have other replicas to stream from). If that is the case, make sure you delete both your `data` directory and your `commitlog` directory and give the node a seed of a node currently up in the cluster. The node should bootstrap with the new config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to resolve this issue:

Step 1 - Calculate the token for the node (replace all occurences of "number_of_tokens" with valid value):

```
python -c 'print [str(((2**64 / number_of_tokens) * i) - 2**63) for i in range(number_of_tokens)]'
```

Step 2 - Reconfigure the token properties in cassandra.yaml:

- comment out num_tokens
- set the token assignment initial_token
- leave auto_bootstrap: true

Step 3 - Delete the following directories. This will ensure that all their contents are cleaned out completely.

- data_file_directories (path is in cassandra.yaml config file)
- commitlog
- saved_caches

Step 4 - Recreate the directories above and make sure Cassandra has full permissions.

Step 5 - Bootstrap the node again by starting DSE.

[Original post here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205199715-Node-startup-fails-with-error-ConfigurationException-Cannot-change-the-number-of-tokens-)